# In Mediation should i include the SDK for all other Networks?

Tags: android, admob, ads, inmobi, millennial-media

I am doing mediation via AdMob, I have added the SDK of Admob,

Now do I need to add only the ADAPTER jar or both the ADAPTER and the SDK of the other AD Networks ?

I am using the Admob SDK for displaying the Ads !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need both the adapter plus the ad network jar.

NB Most ad networks include the adapter (from Admob mediation to their network) in their network jars.

Comment: ADMOB SDK + ADAPATER for inMobi + SDK for inMobi ??

Or just the 

ADMOB SDK + ADAPATER for inMobi ?

Comment: Admob SDK + Adapter for Inmobi + SDK for Inmobi.